# Filling dropdown list with related tables name in JSP

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I have following structure of database created in hibernate4:

DEPARTMENT (has fields: DEPARTMENT_ID and DEPARTMENT_NAME) that I connected through DEPARTMENT_INSTITUTE (has a DEPARTMENT_ID and INSTITUTE_ID) with INSTITUTE (has INSTITUTE_ID and INSTITUTE_NAME) that is later connected through INSTITUTE_TEACHER (by Id's again) with TEACHER (TEACHER_ID, NAME, SURNAME, TITLE).

It all has one to many relationship so one department can have many institutes and one institute can have many teachers.

I would like to basically put it all into an object and through JSTL put it into one dropdown menu (dropdown list doesn't need to have a few levels, it can be all on the same level). The problem is, I don't know:

- How to query all those data and put them into one list,
- Use JSTL in JSP to put them in dropdown menu.

  Could anyone tell me how could I do that? I would love to understand that. Here is the skeleton of method querying for "everything":

[EDIT] so here I made a method for querying from database, if anyone could have a look if it's good solution or not, I would be grateful

```
    public List<String> enlistEverything(){
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<String> toView = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        HashSet<Department> departments = (HashSet<Department>)session.createQuery("FROM Department").list();
        HashSet<Institute> institutes = new HashSet<Institute>();
        HashSet<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<Teacher>();
        
        for(Department d : departments){
            toView.add(d.getDepartmentName());
            institutes.addAll(d.getInstitutes());

        }
        for(Institute i : institutes){
            toView.add(i.getInstituteName());
            teachers.addAll(i.getTeachers());
    }
    for(Teacher t : teachers){
            toView.add(t.getTeacherTitle() + t.getTeacherName() + t.getTeacherSurname());
        }
    }catch(HibernateException e){
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return toView;
    }
```

I've done datamodel using this particular tutorial: http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-1.html so basically inside department class there is a HashSet with institutes and in Institutes there is a hashset with teachers.
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: are you using plain jsp/servlet or any framework for your development?

Comment: It's a plain one, I've just started learning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to basically put it all into an object and through JSTL
>   put it into one dropdown menu (dropdown list doesn't need to have a
>   few levels, it can be all on the same level).

Use a `toView` map instead of a list to keep all the key-value pairs to be put into the dropdown menu.

```
Map<String,String> toView = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
..
..
toView.put(d.getDepartmentId()+"dept",d.getDepartmentName());
toView.put(i.getInstituteId()+"inst",i.getInstituteName());
toView.put(t.getTeacherId()+"teach",t.getTeacherTitle() + t.getTeacherName() + t.getTeacherSurname());
```

Add this `map` to the `request`:

```
Map<String, String> toView = YourDataProvider.enlistEverything();
request.setAttribute("toView", toView);
```

Now in the JSP, use this to put the values in the dropdown menu:

```
<select name="mapData">
    <c:forEach items="${toView}" var="data">
        <option value="${data.key}">${data.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```